# Game Theory - Mixed strategy ESS

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, evolutionary-game-theory

I have a payoff matrix of a symmetric game like this:

$ \begin{matrix}
 & A & B \\
A & (3, 3) & (1, 2) \\
B & (2, 1) & (5, 5) 
\end{matrix}  $

I found that $(A, A)$ and $(B, B)$ are pure strict NE and also $(\frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{3})$ is a mixed NE for both players.

Now how can I check if the mixed NE is also an ESS?

Comment: What have you tried? What is your definition of an ESS? Adding a bounty is no excuse for asking a bad question.

Comment: Also, this is a community. The previous time you asked a question and someone took the time to answer it, you magically disappeared and never acknowledged the efforts someone took to help you.

Comment: ESS is an Evolutionary Stable Strategy